# ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is empty: shelter):

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, postman

I'm making a request from postman and my shelter parameter keeps coming up empty even though I've formatted it to have the shelter parameter encompass the form data correctly. Please help me if I'm missing anything.

```
class Api::V1::SheltersController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @shelters = Shelter.all.order(:id).reverse
    respond_with @shelters
  end

  def show
    @shelter = Shelter.find(params[:id])
    respond_with @shelter
  end

  def create
    @shelter = Shelter.new(shelter_params)
    if @shelter.save
      render json: @shelter, status: 201
    else
      render json: { errors: @shelter.errors.full_messages }, status: 422
    end
  end


  private

    def shelter_params
      params.require(:shelter).permit(:name, :address, :phone, :beds)
    end

end
```

data I'm sending through Postman

```
shelter : {
    name : "Pee's Shelter",
    address : "Pee's Address",
    phone : "(236)817-4853",
    beds : 5
}
```

The request info I'm seeing on the rails page

Parameters:

{"shelter : {\n\t\tname : \"Pee's Shelter\",\n\t\taddress : \"Pee's Address\",\n\t\tphone : \"(236)817-4853\",\n\t\tbeds : 5\n} \n"=>nil, "subdomain"=>"api", "format"=>:json}

Comment: How are you sending the parameters in postman? Raw, form-data or x-www-form-urlencoded?

Comment: Started POST "/shelters" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-12-26 08:14:42 -0800
Processing by Api::V1::SheltersController#create as JSON
  Parameters: {"shelter : {\n\t\tname : \"Pee's Shelter\",\n\t\taddress : \"Pee's Address\",\n\t\tphone : \"(236)817-4853\",\n\t\tbeds : 5\n} \n"=>nil, "subdomain"=>"api"}
Completed 400 Bad Request in 1ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your key is set as:

```
"shelter : {\n\t\tname : \"Pee's Shelter\",\n\t\taddress : \"Pee's Address\",\n\t\tphone : \"(236)817-4853\",\n\t\tbeds : 5\n} \n"
```

And your value for that key is `=> nil`

Remove the `"` before string.

More precisely: don't create your shelter and all the keys as one string.

Comment: I also had it in the didn't have it set to JSON(application/json) thank you so